# libcurl Invalid ELF header in new Arch Install

Tags: elf, dynamic-linking, archlinux

So I just installed Arch and most things are working fine, but when I try to use pacman or curl, I get the error:

```
pacman: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: invalid ELF header
```

Also, I can't seem to run anything pacman-related for now... not even a pacman --help

Not sure if useful, but ls -l /usr/lib | grep libcurl gives:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 594016 Jun 22 12:21 libcurl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jun 22 12:21 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Jun 22 12:21 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 408324 Jun 22 12:21 libcurl.s0.4.3.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: running ./curl-config gives the error, "cannot execute binary file". This makes me wonder if maybe I have a 64 bit version, whilst I'm running Arch i686. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> maybe I have a 64 bit version, whilst I'm running Arch i686

That would do it. Run `file ./curl-config`. If it says `ELF 64-bit LSB executable,...` reinstall `curl` from correct packages.